# Javascript Regular Expression Code to PHP Regular Expressions ?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-replace

I have following java script regular expression which i need to convert to similar php converter.

```
text = text.replace(/R/g, "ූ");
```

Can someone help me to convert this into PHP ?

Comment: Just to replace letter `R` you don't even need a regex

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php if you really want to use a regular expression for replacing a character. Otherwise use http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: `str_replace('R', '...');`

Comment: no i need regex, becos this just a peice of code only, plus i know i how to do it but only issue is i dont how to do the \g in the php ?

Answer (score 1):

its regex counterpart in php will be :

```
preg_replace( '/R/', 'your replacement string', $text );
```

$text = the value of 'text' in your javascript code.

*However, for simple text replace, regular expressions are expensive. If your problem can't be solved using simple string functions then only use regex.*

Comment: i dont think there is a option "\g" , that the problem

Comment: sorry, my mistake, '/R/' will do

Answer (score 1):

It's very similar:

```
$text = preg_replace('/R/', "ූ", $text);
```

Have look at  the [preg_replace documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: how do i add the option option "\g" ??

Comment: @mahen3d: There is no option `g`, it is implicit with preg_replace.